# Datastore does not update mutableStateOf to update the view

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using `DataStore` to hold a `boolean` and depending on the value the view will change. The value does change and works sort of, it is just the app requires a restart for the change to take. Is this because of the `runBlocking`?

This is the `suspend fun` I'm calling

```
    suspend fun isOnBoardingCompleted(): Boolean {
        return context
            .dataStore
            .data
            .map { preferences -> preferences[ON_BOARDING_COMPLETED] ?: false }
            .first()
    }
```

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val projectViewModel: ProjectRoomViewModel by viewModels()

    @OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val projectRoomViewModel: ProjectRoomViewModel by viewModels()

        setContent {
            val preferences = DataStoreViewModel(this)
            val isOnBoardingCompleted = remember {
                mutableStateOf(
                    runBlocking {
                        preferences.isOnBoardingCompleted()
                    }
                )
            }
            AppTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {

                    if (isOnBoardingCompleted.value) {
                        RootScreen( preferences = preferences, projectRoomViewModel = projectRoomViewModel)
                    } else {
                        PagerView(navController = rememberNavController()) {
                                mutableStateOf(
                                   runBlocking{
                                        preferences.disableOnboarding()
                                    }
                                )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In MainActivity, you create the same viewModel twice, fyi

Comment: Ah look at that, I do. Thank you @CCT